# Best way to do user control code behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, methods, static

I have this very simple control below. And on the page that i use this control I'd just like to be able to say: `ucMessagePanel.SetMessage(...)`, but it does not allow me to declare a static method. I tried doing it with Static properties and that works just fine, but shouldn't I also be able to use static methods?

```
    <center>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMessage" runat="server" >
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</center>


public partial class ucMessagePanel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{        
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static void SetMessage(string message, string mssgCssClass)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = message;
        pnlMessage.CssClass = mssgCssClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need static methods. When you declare the user control in the ASPX page, you can reference it directly by the ID.

In the ASPX:

```
<uc:SomeUserControl ID="UserControl1" runat="server" ...>
```

And in the code behind:

```
UserControl1.SetMessage("Some message");
```

In the user control, change the method to something like this:

```
public void SetMessage(string Message)
{
    lblMessage.Text = Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can't access items contained on an instance of the control. For example; if you had two concurrent requests running; and you call the static method; which instance of the `ucMessagePanel` class would it modify (this even bypassing the issue of the code provided couldn't compile)?

There is no way you should have been able to edit those controls with a static property either, unless you were taking the value of the static property and assigning it to the control using an instance method.

You should avoid using `static` in ASP.NET request processing unless it is something you need to share between request threads.